# How to validate reactive input field only when one is filled?

Tags: angular, angular8

How to validate reactive input field only when one is filled?

My reactive form is:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      code: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')]],
      dateFrom: [null, []],
      dateTo: [null, []],
      uk: [null, []]
    });
```

I need to validate `dateTo` only when `dateFrom` is filled.

Comment: you create a customValidate over all the form or over dateTo, see (and it's only one of several examples): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120135/best-way-to-implement-angular-cross-field-validation/57123631#57123631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom Validator:

in TS:

```
checkFirstDate(group: FormGroup) {  
  let dateFrom = group.controls.dateFrom.value;
  return dateFrom ? null : { dateFromNotExist: true }     
}


this.form = this.fb.group({
      code: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')]],
      dateFrom: [null, []],
      dateTo: [null, []],
      uk: [null, []]
    }, {validator: this.checkFirstDate });
```

in HTML

```
   <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.hasError('dateFromNotExist') && (form.get('dateTo').dirty || form.get('dateTo').touched)">
    Fill Date Form first
   </span>
```

Comment: no , return null if the dateForm field is  filled ,  else( if empty  ) return error validattion

Comment: @GhoulAhmed, if you'r using material error, and want to show an error in a "input" when the error is defined in a "form" you need use errorStateMatcher. See a discussion about this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876119/both-mat-error-show-when-only-one-condition-is-true. Any way in your validator you don't take account **dateTo** ¿?

Comment: i produce your example without mat-error :)  [demo working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sn3aa7)